# How to make simple if statement bubble style?

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement, codeigniter-3

How make this if-statement more simple  ? , as a function it's working well but i think it's not good on coding.

this is the code :

```
        if (empty($checkMaxID)) 
        {
            $this->model->insert_temp_code($code_request,$cabang_code);
        }

        $checkHasTempCode = $this->model->checkHasTempCode($user_id);

        if ($checkMaxID['tempcode_created_by'] !=  $user_id ) {
            $data['code_request'] = str_pad($checkMaxID['tempcode_value'] + 1, 5, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);        

            if (empty($checkHasTempCode) ) {
                $this->model->insert_temp_code($data['code_request'],$cabang_code);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $data['code_request'] = $code_request;
        }

`
```

anyone can help me please ?

Thank you

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

Use ternary operator when you have if else condition. Also, you can avoid nested if thorough multiple conditions in a single if statements. I hope this will helps.

```
$checkHasTempCode = $this->model->checkHasTempCode($user_id);
if (empty($checkMaxID))  {
    $this->model->insert_temp_code($code_request,$cabang_code);
}

$data['code_request'] = ( $checkMaxID['tempcode_created_by'] !=  $user_id ) ? 
str_pad($checkMaxID['tempcode_value'] + 1, 5, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT) : $code_request;
if ( empty($checkHasTempCode) && $checkMaxID['tempcode_created_by'] !=  $user_id ) {
    $this->model->insert_temp_code($data['code_request'],$cabang_code);
}
```